# Calling setState causes infinite build() loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the [intl_phone_number_input](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl_phone_number_input/latest/) flutter package to validate a phone number on a login form.

The idea is to make my the "CONTINUE" button become enabled/clickable once the phone number entered is valid.

So here's my code:

```
class Otp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Otp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Otp> createState() => _OtpState();
}

class _OtpState extends State<Otp> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final otpController = TextEditingController();
  late String initialCountry;
  late PhoneNumber number;
  String validNumber = "";
  bool phoneNumberIsValid = false;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String verificationId;
  bool otpCodeSent = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    String locale = Platform.localeName;
    print("Platform locale: ${Platform.localeName.substring(locale.length - 2, locale.length)}");
    String countryCode = Platform.localeName.substring(locale.length - 2, locale.length);
    number = PhoneNumber(isoCode: countryCode);
    super.initState();
  }

  // OTP OR PHONE NUMBER INPUT
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: otpCodeSent ? otpColumn() : Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                  this.number = number;
                  print("Input changed to: ${number.phoneNumber}");
                },
                onInputValidated: (bool value) {
                  if (value == true){
                    print("onInputValidated number: ${number.phoneNumber}");
                    setState(() {
                      this.number = number;
                      phoneNumberIsValid = true;
                    });
                    print("onInputValidated number: ${number.phoneNumber}");
                  }
                },
                selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(
                  selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
                ),
                ignoreBlank: false,
                autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                selectorTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                initialValue: number,
                textFieldController: phoneNumberController,
                formatInput: false,
                keyboardType:
                    TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
                // inputBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30)),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: !phoneNumberIsValid ? null : () async { 
                String? phoneNumber = number.phoneNumber;
                print("Phone number is: $phoneNumber");
                if (phoneNumber == null){ return;}
                if (phoneNumberIsValid){
                  print("VALID NUMBER, SEND CODE");
                  _verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNumber);
                } else {
                  print("INVALID NUMBER, COULD NOT SEND CODE");       
                }
              },
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: phoneNumberIsValid ? 1 : 0.4,
                child: RowButton("CONTINUE", Icons.arrow_forward_sharp)
              ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see above, the idea is to save the inputted phone number in the `number` variable, until the inputted number is valid, in which case it then fires `setState()` inside the `onInputValidated` callback to make the "CONTINUE" button clickable, as well as saving the number.

However this causes `onInputValidated` to be called infinite times, with no user interation:

```
I/flutter (26758): Input changed to: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): Input changed to: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): Input changed to: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): Input changed to: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): Input changed to: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
I/flutter (26758): onInputValidated number: +XXXXXXXXXX
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you call `setState` in `onInputValidated`.

You should not reassign the value of `number`, or that will cause an infinite loop where `onInputValidated` and `onInputChanged` just keep calling each other.

Try to simply remove the `this.number = number;` line.

If that causes a problem, you could use another variable in wich you save the validated number (something like `this.validatedNumber = number;`), that should prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: Removing `this.number = number` in `setState` did not fix anything. Removing `this.number = number` in `onInputChanged` fixed the loop, but then the phoneNumber wasn't saved for when the input is validated. PS: I need to call setState to update the UI when the input is validated.

Comment: I tried to test your code, and couldn't reproduce the issue (no infinite loop occoured). Maybe you did not post the full source code?